# How to write a file in specific data volume

Tags: go

I am trying to write in newly generated file in a specific attached volume to my container (a directory)

however i am not sure about the correct the syntax. Below my code:

```
// Write the certificates to disk
    f, _ := os.Create(filepath.Join("/data/certs/", "chamscertificate.pem"))
    f.Write(cert)
    f.Close()

    f, _ = os.Create("key.pem")
    f.Write(key)
    f.Close()
}
```

when executing "go run .", i get the "key.pem" but not the "certificate.pem".

Comment: Why are you ignoring all errors?

Answer (score 0):

You don't check for errors. If the file wasn't created, the information about why the file wasn't created will be in the error return value from `os.Create`.

```
f, err := os.Create(filepath.Join("/data/certs/", "chamscertificate.pem"))
if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
}
... etc.
```

Note that `f.Write` and `f.Close` also return errors that should be checked.